# How to install RVM system requirements without giving sudo access for RVM user

Tags: ruby, deployment, rvm, sudo

On my Debian server I have a user called "deployer" that does not have `sudo` access, and has RVM installed.

When installing Ruby using "deployer", like 1.9.3, it triggers a task to install dependencies

```
"Installing requirements for debian, might require sudo password."
```

which fails and stops installation because "deployer" can not sudo.

I don't want to add "deployer" into the sudoers list, and don't want to install RVM for some other user just for a one-time use for installing dependencies.

What is the correct way to install that dependencies? Or how do I list them to install manually?

Comment: Rvm might be attempting to install build dependencies in order to compile a source release of ruby. Avoid the "latest" version and specify an explicit version of ruby.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This is indeed a new feature of RVM called `autolibs`, which automatically installs dependencies.

If you have already installed RVM, and it is asking you for your `sudo` password, you can disable autolibs:

```
$ rvm autolibs disable
$ rvm requirements # manually install these
$ rvm install ruby
```

Otherwise, you can install RVM without autolibs with this command:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --autolibs=read-fail
```

I understand the motivation, but find it rather annoying. I do not want to put my sudo password into RVM, nor for that matter Bundle! Please community, stop doing this.

Comment: Thank you, I've wasted a lot of time with this. What were they thinking?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `curl` prefixed with a slash? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Gili The backslash will bypass an existing alias, which may have additional unwanted flags.

Comment: One main purpose of virtualenvs is to avoid using root privileges, which asking for root password entirely ruins it.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi I couldn't agree more.  Your comment is perfect.

Comment: Why am I getting `No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.` in the `install ruby` step?... How do I validate it?

Comment: I wonder why they do not add this to installation steps in `rvm` site. Don't they understand that a lot,if not most, people will not want to perform a privileged installation?

Comment: I think you need to say `rvm autolibs read-fail` now instead of `... disable` or `rvm requirements` will say nothing.

Answer (score 38):

I prefer this

```
$ rvm autolibs fail
$ rvm install ruby
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Missing required packages: gawk g++ gcc make libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

then I can relogin with root and run

```
# apt-get install gawk g++ gcc make libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219765/14731) fails to install Ruby into `.rvm/bin/ruby`. The shell script ends up in `.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby` which is a pain if your build script depends on this location and the version number changes over time.

Here is an easier solution that worked for me:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles --autolibs=0 --ruby
```

`.rvm/bin/ruby` is created as expected.

**Source**: http://blog.sunild.com/2013/07/install-ruby-with-rvm-on-mac-os-108.html

Answer (score -1):

The problem was introduced somewhere in the latest RVM versions. Don't know exactly when, but definitely in the past 3-4 months.

Try this:

```
rvm get 1.18.8
rvm install <whichever-version-you-want>
```

I don't know exactly when on the path between 1.18.8 and 1.20.12 that problem got introduced, but for me the installation works with RVM v1.18.8 and fails with v1.20.12.

Comment: Downgrading is certainly not required.