# Dreamhost vps can't install rvm because requires being superuser

Tags: rvm, vps, dreamhost

I followed this [wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM)‎ (and others) and the problem is simple: 
I can have a sudo user from panel that can't do anything with my web site. But my usual user can't run as a superuser. 
So there is no way so far that I get rvm to install on my vps.

I'm tired of searching, can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [RVM site](http://rvm.io/rvm/install):

> Without [autolibs](http://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs)
>
> ```
> $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --autolibs=read-fail
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should *only* need sudo access for this if the bundle install fails on mysql2, to update apt-get and re-install libmysqlclient-dev if necessary. You should be able to handle those parts from the correct location with your "admin" user, then do whatever you need again from your regular user the site is hosted on.

This article will walk you through setting up RVM with a full Rails stack on a regular shell account. There is no need to even add an admin user to your VPS to perform this install, and you get to leave all of your services fully managed!!!

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM#Do_Magic

If you have any other questions please do not hesitate to ask us, you can send our support team a ticket here https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=support.msg& or you can even hit us up for support on Twitter @DreamHostCare

Thanks!
Matt C
DreamHost Staff

Comment: Nop, I still can't install rvm

Comment: Since admin users have now been removed (on new VPS servers anyway), this post has the correct fix when trying to install a ruby version using RVM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563115/how-to-install-rvm-system-requirements-without-giving-sudo-for-rvm-user/17219765#17219765. I installed RVM fine, but had to disable autolibs afterward to be able to install a ruby version. Dreamhost's documentation has not been updated to deal with the (now in effect) removal of admin accounts.