# Permission denied error while installing Nokogiri 1.6.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, permission-denied

I get a permission denied error while installing Nokogiri 1.6.1.2.

The error is:

```
While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)     Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/build_info/nokogiri-1.6.1.info
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stack overflow. it would help us to help you if you were to add a bit more explanation to your question. Otherwise we have to *guess* :  what you were doing to cause this error? what your setup its? what research you have done on the topic already? In future, can you please edit your question and add all this information?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've installed RVM on the root level. This post might help you solve this issue:

"[How to install RVM system requirements without giving sudo access for RVM user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563115/how-to-install-rvm-system-requirements-without-giving-sudo-for-rvm-user)"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I used RailsInstaller back in 2013, it placed RVM at the system level (which causes problems).

All you need to do is uninstall then reinstall RVM. Here is the most detailed way of uninstalling RVM: "[How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system/25571648#25571648)"